# How can i get a int value of a sql query in a php variable ? So i can later use it calculate with php variables

Tags: php, mysql

```
  $sql = "Select SUM(credit) as totaal_number from table_numbers";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        print_r($row, true);
        $number2 = $row['0'];
        }

$number1 = 5000;
$total = $number1 - $number2;
echo $total;
```

I know the value of number2 must be 1000 , but don't get as output 4000, please help me.

Comment: What do you get? What is `$number2` returning?

Comment: no need to use while loop ..

Comment: Although not the cause of your issue, the `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated for years. Don't use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $number2 = $row[0];
```

use something like that

Comment: `'0'` as an array index is automatically coerced to an integer [as shown here](http://ideone.com/B3sCfA). This is not the cause of the issue.

Comment: so right tick the answer so someone other can get in touch with the answer easily